# Java Apache POI Excel Numeric Cell value with Locale pt-BR

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, locale, cell

I want to set the `XSSFCell` in Excel to display the `CellType` as numeric, and need it to diplay the value as `pt-BR Locale` (with `.` for separator instead of `,` (not decimal/fractional - but still `double`). I managed to diplay the correct cell value, but the `CellTyle` only gets `String`. I know that `double` have the US configuration `0.000,00`, and a simple `NumberFormat` with `Locale` do the trick, but the `CellType` gets to `text`, not `number`.

The number already comes configured with Locale, which comes straight from Database. (Eg: `412.000`), but double converts it to US (`412,000`).

So, how can I format the cell to my `Locale` and still set the `CellType` as `Numeric` ?

This is what I got so far:

```
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(anyCellNumber);
    double value = 412.000; //valueThatComesFromDataBaseWithLocaleFormatted
    cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
    //At this point, double has already converted the cell value to 412,000 - So, What I did was:
    cell.setCellValue(String.format("%.3f", value).replace(",", ".")); // Replaced the , to . to match Locale
```

So, this is the point, the `CellType` is set, but `NumberFormat`, `DecimalFormat`, `Locale`, `String.format`, etc, gets the `cellvalue` to `String`, and thus the `CellType` is `text`.

Can´t use `Double.parseDouble(valueFormatted.toString())` because it throws `Exception`, if the `String` is `Locale` formatted.

So, how (if it is possible), can I have a `CellType.NUMERIC` AND the cell value formatted for my `Locale` (pt-BR)???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/LocaleUtil.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you specifically want your Cell to be of type numeric and your display to be something "not Date" ? The only approach that I clould think of would be to define your own cellStyle. This is possible in excel with custom functions. In apache-poi it could be possible when tinkering around with cell Styles:

```
 ...
 Cell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex);
 CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
 CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
 createHelper.createDataFormat("some specific custom data format").
 cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

I am however not sure that there is a way. I am not sure but these cellStyles seem to be limited to the default excel styles https://www.roseindia.net/java/poi/setdataformat.shtml

The simplest approach would be to make your cell of Type "Date". Even if your result from the Database is a number, it can be converted to Date, since Date is only a layer upon a timestamp. I would highly suggest to look at this approch instead of "hacking" your way around number fromats looking similar to Dates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your aproach, but still couldn´t get it done. I am beggining to think that you are right, the cells might be limited to default excel styles. But thanks anyway

Comment: Glad that you are making progress :)